# 2019 Developer Survey data set is available for download

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2019, announcement

Anonymized results of the 2019 Developer Survey are available under the Open Database License, allowing you to download and analyze the dataset. Certain survey answers are treated as personally identifiable information, and therefore excluded from the anonymized results.

[Download the .csv file](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/)

This year, we are partnering with [Glitch](https://glitch.com/) to publish and highlight this data. This means you can access the data on our site, and you can [explore the dataset on Glitch](http://culture-zine.glitch.me/culture/p/ce58420f-771e-46bf-b941-21e553163898/).

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Thanks!

You'll still have to update the [survey result page](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019), though:

[image: Image featuring below text]

> Want to dive into the results yourself? Check back in a few weeks, when the anonymized results of the survey will be available for download under the Open Database License (ODbL). We look forward to seeing what you find!

Comment: We just fixed the survey result page.

Comment: @AnitaTaylor thanks. edited my answer to reflect this.